# laravel Modal request return nothing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4

first I make a modal bootstrap and everything work fine but I dnt know why I try to return this request->input('w_name'); It return nothing

Note . I want to get output like , if I type Hello It should return Hello instead of nothing

```
<form action="{{route('warehouse-name.update',$wa->id)}}" method="post" role="form" id="add-form-{{$wa->id}}" >
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('PATCH')}}
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Test : <input type="text" value="{{$wa->name}}" name="w_name">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#add-form-{{$wa->id}}').submit()">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did your modal send correct? Did you see request at Network tab of your browser's dev tools window? It had your POST information in it?

Comment: no It didnt get request but if I just return 'x'; it will get x out put

Comment: in form-data It return _token and method patch

Comment: `w_name` doesn't exists in form-data or it's just has empty value?

Comment: doesn't exist in form-data

Comment: Try to move input right after `method_field`, see what you got.

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException error  well, in my web.php . i use only Route::patch should i use post too ?

Comment: Nope, you didn't. You don't need to remove `method_field`, your input must go on next line after it.

Comment: I mean may be it problem with HTML nesting because you got first two inputs and didn't had nested.